# I am trying to do an update for a list of dictionaries in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have to update the list of dictionaries, more precisely: if the value is greater than 70 then the value associated then the key should be uppercase, otherwise if it is less than or equal to 70 it should be lowercase.
I tried to use a for loop but I get this error for k,v in list():

```
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

This is what I have so far:

```
list = [{'brand':'nokia', "age":"56"}, {'brand':'motorola', "age":"80"}, {'brand':'sony', "age":"42"}, {'brand':'allview', "age":"10"}, {'brand':'huawei', "age":"15"}] 

for k,v in list(): 
    if v > 50: 
        list[k].upper() 
    else:
        list[k].lower() 

print = list()
```

Comment: Hi can you please provide some sample data, intended results and maybe something you have tried already?  Thanks!

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. It is important for the community that you *also* demonstrate that you are working to solve your issue. The best way to do that in my opinion is to include the **text** based version of the source code you have so far, even if it is not working quite right.

Comment: list = [{'brand':'nokia', "age":"56"},
        {'brand':'motorola', "age":"80"},
        {'brand':'sony', "age":"42"},
        {'brand':'allview', "age":"10"},
        {'brand':'huawei', "age":"15"}]

for k,v in list():
    if v > 50:
        list[k].upper()
    else:
        list[k].lower()

print = list()
* this is what I have so far I'm new to this and I'm not getting things quite right . I appreciate very much your help . I hope I will understand this fast in the future

Comment: list = [{'brand':'nokia', "age":"56"},
        {'brand':'motorola', "age":"80"},
        {'brand':'sony', "age":"42"},
        {'brand':'allview', "age":"10"},
        {'brand':'huawei', "age":"15"}]

for k,v in list():
    if v > 50:
        list[k].upper()
    else:
        list[k].lower()

print = list()

Answer (score 0):

Starting with the error that you're getting, it is because you need to iterate on the list elements first before using the key, value pair to iterate over dictionary items.

Now, if your list is:

```
my_list = [{'brand':'nokia', "age":"56"}, {'brand':'motorola', "age":"80"}, {'brand':'sony', "age":"42"}, {'brand':'allview', "age":"10"}, {'brand':'huawei', "age":"15"}]
```

Just run this code:

```
for my_dict in my_list:
    age_value = int(my_dict["age"])
    brand_value = my_dict["brand"]
    if age_value > 70:
        my_dict["brand"] = brand_value.upper()
    else:
        my_dict["brand"] = brand_value.lower()
```

and you'll get the result as:

```
[{'brand': 'nokia', 'age': '56'},
 {'brand': 'MOTOROLA', 'age': '80'},
 {'brand': 'sony', 'age': '42'},
 {'brand': 'allview', 'age': '10'},
 {'brand': 'huawei', 'age': '15'}]
```

PS - The usage of 'list' for your list is not recommended since it's a bad practice because 'list' is a data type, you should change it to something like 'my_list'.

Comment: @Andy did that solve the problem you were facing?

Comment: yes thank you very much for your help on this :) really appreciate it

Comment: @Andy happy to help! If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score -1):

Given your code, I made the following solution providing an uppercase value of 'brand' if the age of the company is over 70.

```
list = [{'brand':'nokia', "age":"56"}, {'brand':'motorola', "age":"80"}, {'brand':'sony', "age":"42"}, {'brand':'allview', "age":"10"}, {'brand':'huawei', "age":"15"}] 
 
#set the range n for index 0,n to the number of dictionary entries in your list.

for index in range(0,5):
    print(list[index]["age"])
    # if list([index]["age"])>70:
    #     print("old asF")
    int_value = int(list[index]["age"])
  #here we reassign the value of 'brand' to be 'brand'.upper()
    if int_value >70:
    list[index]['brand'] = list[index]['brand'].upper()

        

print(list)
```

gives the following output

```
 [{'brand': 'nokia', 'age': '56'}, {'brand': 'MOTOROLA', 'age': '80'}, {'brand': 'sony', 'age': '42'}, {'brand': 'allview', 'age': '10'}, {'brand': 'huawei', 'age': '15'}]
```

Comment: thank you this looks great but maybe I wasn't very clear about my issue because I need the output of 'brand' to be upper case when the values of age are >70 and lowercase when these are <70 . I was thinking that I need to give the keys 'upper()' so that the value from the keys like 'brand' is upper when the 'age' is >70 and lower when the age is <70

Comment: hey Andy, you had it right with the .upper() command. corrected to provide the solution! hopefully that works

Answer (score -1):

what you want maybe:

```
s = [{'brand':'nokia', "age":"56"}, {'brand':'motorola', "age":"80"}, {'brand':'sony', "age":"42"}, {'brand':'allview', "age":"10"}, {'brand':'huawei', "age":"15"}] 
[ {'brand': item['brand'].upper() if int(item['age'])>70 else item['brand'], 'AGE' if int(item['age']) > 70 else 'age': item['age']} for item in s]
```

the output is:

```
[{'brand': 'nokia', 'age': '56'}, {'brand': 'MOTOROLA', 'AGE': '80'}, {'brand': 'sony', 'age': '42'}, {'brand': 'allview', 'age': '10'}, {'brand': 'huawei', 'age': '15'}]
```

Comment: this looks great but maybe I wasn't very clear about my issue because I need the output of 'brand' to be upper case when the values of age are >70 and lowercase when these are <70 .

Comment: change the key 'brand' to upper case when age is great than 70?

or change the value of 'brand' to upper case?


or change both of them?

Comment: only change the value of 'brand' to upper case

Comment: I appreciate very much your help on this